# How to run tasks from another server using Celery?

Tags: python, django, celery

I have 2 different Python applications using Celery connected to the same broker.

**Server A** has all my @tasks, but I need to execute this tasks from **Server B**. I cannot do the standard import tasks as it does not exist on server B.

How in Celery from server B can I run tasks from exist only on Server A?

i.e.

Server B:

```
from tasksFromSeverA import add
add.delay(4, 4)
```

Is there something in Celery that allows you send a signal to run say a task called 'Add' to the Broker?

Comment: Hey @Prometheus, Have you got any optimize solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as i know you can't execute a task in "Server B" that is not implemented in "Server B".

What you can do is execute a task in "Server A" from "Server B". You can achieve this using the send_task function as explained in this link:

http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-call-a-task-by-name

Comment: sent task is what I was after, maybe I did not explain this very well. thank you for the linked. Now I know what it is called.